# cant make correct validation of input= text

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate subscribers name , I just need to find if a string contains any numbers and alert the error message if not it then the user should get the message "your contact info is valid". Now by creating simple function , but it does not work, why is that ?

html code:

```
<input id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text" required>
<input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" required>
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
```

js code:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

submitButton.onclick = function(){
if(email.value.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.value.lastIndexOf(".") - email.value.indexOf("@") < 2)
        if(hasNumbers(name.value))
        alert("Please enter valid contact info");
        return false;
```

function hasNumbers(t)
     return /\d/.test(t);

Comment: Please provide the html code

Comment: Please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
submitButton.onclick = function(){
     var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
     if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(name))
        alert("Please enter valid contact info");
        return false;
}
```

Please try like this

Comment: nope , it does not work, that's the problem , I did the same thing over and over , but it just doesn't recognize numbers and says that everything's fine

Comment: Which field you need to validate name or email?

Comment: name. Since email validation works. Its like If I enterd both name and email correctly it still says that it is wrong. I dont even know where the mistake could be

Comment: the fiddle you sent - is not working either.. have any solutions ?

Comment: if(email.value.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.value.lastIndexOf(".") - email.value.indexOf("@") < 2)  What did you mean by this?

Comment: that if there is no @ symbol or dot symbol it would throw an error

Comment: Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/aswathyb950/ec7kot4L/ . I have added validations for both fields

Comment: nah, it is you , who I should be thankfull for this ;) really appreciate